# Marshal/unmarshal XML list containing elements with same name to different specific variables

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

Using MOXy (or any other java XML framework) is it possible to perform the following marshalling and unmarshalling between this xml and object:

```
<teacher>
    <field name="Age">30</field>
    <field name="Name">Bob</field>
    <field name="Course">Math</field>
</teacher>
```

```
public class Teacher {
   Field age;
   Field name;
   Field course;
}

public class Field {
    String name;
    String value;
}
```

There are solutions that work for marshalling (annotating all fields with `@XmlElement(name= "field")`) and there are some solutions that work for unmarshalling (`@XmlPath("field[@name='Age']/text()")` .

Is there however a solution that works both ways, or an approach that will unmarshal and marshal XML between these two formats?

Answer (score 0):

Using JAXB's `xjc` tool to generate JAXB classes from an XML Schema yields:

```
xjc -no-header teacher.xsd
```

**Teacher.java**

```
package generated;

import java.util.*;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "field" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher
{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Field> field;
    public List<Field> getField()
    {
        if (field == null)
            field = new ArrayList<>();
        return this.field;
    }
}
```

**Field.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "field")
public class Field
{
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String value) { this.name = value; }
}
```

From this XML schema:

**teacher.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>

    <xs:element name="teacher">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="field"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="field">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

To address the comment *"I wish to not unmarshal my XML into a list of Field but into their own distinct "age", "name" and "course" variables."*, here is a revised XML schema to inject properties for "age", "name" and "course":

**teacher.xsd (revised)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ci="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"
    xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="ci"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
    <xs:element name="teacher">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <ci:code>
<![CDATA[
    private java.util.Map<String,String> fieldMap;
    public java.util.Map<String,String> getFieldMap()
    {
        if ( fieldMap == null )
        {
            fieldMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
            for ( Field field : getField() )
                fieldMap.put(field.getName(), field.getValue());
        }
        return fieldMap;
    }

    public String getAge() { return getFieldMap().get("Age"); }
    public void setAge(String value) { getFieldMap().put("Age", value); }
                    
    public String getName() { return getFieldMap().get("Name"); }
    public void setName(String value) { getFieldMap().put("Name", value); }
                    
    public String getCourse() { return getFieldMap().get("Course"); }
    public void setCourse(String value) { getFieldMap().put("Course", value); }
]]>
                    </ci:code>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="field"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="field">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

To generate the revised `Teacher` class, use:

```
xjc -no-header -extension -Xinject-code teacher.xsd
```

**Teacher.java (revised)**

```
package generated;

import java.util.*;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "field" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher
{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Field> field;
    public List<Field> getField()
    {
        if (field == null)
            field = new ArrayList<>();
        return this.field;
    }

    private java.util.Map<String,String> fieldMap;
    public java.util.Map<String,String> getFieldMap()
    {
        if ( fieldMap == null )
        {
            fieldMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
            for ( Field field : getField() )
                fieldMap.put(field.getName(), field.getValue());
        }
        return fieldMap;
    }

    public String getAge() { return getFieldMap().get("Age"); }
    public void setAge(String value) { getFieldMap().put("Age", value); }
                    
    public String getName() { return getFieldMap().get("Name"); }
    public void setName(String value) { getFieldMap().put("Name", value); }
                    
    public String getCourse() { return getFieldMap().get("Course"); }
    public void setCourse(String value) { getFieldMap().put("Course", value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

I know that making a list of the fields will work perfectly fine. However, I wish to not unmarshal my XML into a list of Field but into their own distinct "age", "name" and "course" variables.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Powershell script with and Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

class Teacher {
   [int]$Age
   [string]$Name
   [string]$Course
}

class Field {
    [string]$Name
    [string]$Value
}

class Content {
   $Teachers = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
   $Fields = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
}

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$Contents = [Content]::new()

#Parse Xml to classes
foreach($xTeacher in $xDoc.Descendants('teacher'))
{
    $teacher = [Teacher]::new()
    $Contents.Teachers.Add($teacher) | out-null
    
    foreach($xField in $xTeacher.Elements('field'))
    {
        $name = $xField.Attribute('name').Value
        $value = $xField.Value

        $field = [Field]::new()
        $field.Name = $name 
        $field.Value = $value
        $Contents.Fields.Add($field) | out-null

        $teacher.$name = $value
    }
}

#create new XMl File
$ident = '<teachers></teachers>'
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($ident)
$xTeachers = $xDoc.Root

foreach($teacher in $Contents.Teachers)
{
   $xTeacher = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('teacher'))
   $xTeachers.Add($xTeacher) | out-null

   $field = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('field'), $teacher.Age)
   $name = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::Get('name'), 'Age')
   $field.Add($name) | out-null
   $xTeacher.Add($field) | out-null

   $field = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('field'), $teacher.Name)
   $name = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::Get('name'), 'Name')
   $field.Add($name) | out-null
   $xTeacher.Add($field) | out-null

   $field = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('field'), $teacher.Course)
   $name = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::Get('name'), 'Course')
   $field.Add($name) | out-null
   $xTeacher.Add($field) | out-null
   
}

$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Here is the xml file

```
<teachers>
   <teacher>
      <field name="Age">30</field>
      <field name="Name">Bob</field>
      <field name="Course">Math</field>
   </teacher>
</teachers>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

This looks nice. I am however sadly bound to using Java to do the marshalling and unmarshalling. Apologies for this missing information, I have specified it more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an solution using MOXy

```
  @Test
  @SneakyThrows
  void testMarshal() {

    // Marshalling
    Teacher teacher =
        new Teacher(new Field("age", "30"), new Field("name", "Bob"), new Field("course", "Math"));

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Teacher.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    marshaller.marshal(teacher, System.out);

    // Unmarshalling
    String xml =
        """
        <teacher>
            <field name="age">30</field>
            <field name="name">Bob</field>
            <field name="course">Math</field>
        </teacher>""";

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Teacher unmarshalledTeacher = (Teacher) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));

    System.out.printf("Unmarshalled: %s, %s, %s%n",
            unmarshalledTeacher.getAge(),
            unmarshalledTeacher.getName(),
            unmarshalledTeacher.getCourse());
  }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "teacher")
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class Teacher {
  @XmlPath("field[@name='age']")
  private Field age;

  @XmlPath("field[@name='name']")
  private Field name;

  @XmlPath("field[@name='course']")
  private Field course;
}

@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class Field {
  @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @XmlValue
  private String value;

  void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m){
        name = null;
      }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teacher>
   <field name="age">30</field>
   <field name="name">Bob</field>
   <field name="course">Math</field>
</teacher>
Unmarshalled: Field(name=age, value=30), Field(name=name, value=Bob), Field(name=course, value=Math)
```

The `beforeMarshal()` is a dirty getaround for the fact that attributes are duplicated when marshalling. I made an issue here https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/2022